# Navbar toggler icon won't be appeared when using bootstrap 5

Tags: html

I just want to write a simple code in order to have the navbar toggler icon appeared on a html page. The toggler icon doesn't appear on the page, the three links are displayed which should be contained by the toggler icon instead. Here is the code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<title>Navbar</title>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<nav class="navbar-expand-sm bg-dark navbar-dark py-3 justify-content-between justify-content-sm-start">
<div class="container-fluid">
<a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Logo</a>
<button class="navbar-toggler" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#idCollapse">
<span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
</button>
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="idCollapse">
<ul class="navbar-nav">
<li class="nav-item">
<a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
</li>
<li class="nav-item">
<a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
</li>
<li class="nav-item">
<a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
</li>
</ul>
</div>
</div>
</nav>
</body>
</html>
```

Thanks for your help in advance: Bazsa

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <title>Navbar</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>

<body>
  <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-xxl bg-dark navbar-dark py-3 justify-content-between justify-content-xxl-start">
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Logo</a>
      <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#idCollapse">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
      </button>
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="idCollapse">
        <ul class="navbar-nav">
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </nav>
  
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-ka7Sk0Gln4gmtz2MlQnikT1wXgYsOg+OMhuP+IlRH9sENBO0LRn5q+8nbTov4+1p" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

You are missing the `navbar` class in your `<nav>`.

Change

`<nav class="navbar-expand-sm bg-dark navbar-dark py-3 justify-content-between justify-content-sm-start">`

to

`<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm bg-dark navbar-dark py-3 justify-content-between justify-content-sm-start">`

and your navbar should give a hamburger at small screens.

EDIT: There was an issue regarding your CDN link as well. The above snippet should work for you. :)

Comment: Yes, I miswrote this. After replacing it, the problem still persisits. Thanks anyway.

Comment: Yes, I saw. I replaced the CDN links, and it works now. Please check.